# Prevent downtime while building create-react-app on server

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm hosting a create-react-app on an Amazon EC2 instance and each time I deploy a new version of the web app, i.e. run `yarn react-scripts build`, I have a downtime of several minutes until the app builds. The app is being served directly from the `build/` folder by `serve ./build -s`.

I thought about serving from a different folder, e.g. `deployed/` and copying to it only once the build into the `build/` folder is finished. That should minimize the downtime. But I did not find anybody else recommending that practice and if it was really recommended, I would guess that `react-scripts build` would do something similar out-of-the-box, to prevent serving partially built assets.

So my question is whether there is some standard way to prevent downtime while building the assets on the server.

Comment: Typically you wouldn't use CRA on your hosting server, but build your application `locally` or on a dedicated `build server` or `CI/CD-pipeline` and then move the produced build to your hosting server. If you want to keep your current workflow the approach of using a different build directory could solve your problem.

Comment: I had this exact same idea, but no one seems to be suggesting it